# Light weight datagrid component for flex mobile\iOS?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, list, datagrid, itemrenderer

I know that we do not have a table\datagrid component for flex mobile apps. Currently I am developing an iPad app, in which I am using datagrid(though it says it's not optimized), which works quite well on iPad. There were no scrolling issues(which I felt would be present). But only problem is while switching the tabs below, it takes very long time to move from one tab to another(it just hangs for few seconds before moving). When i removed datagrid, it was working fine again. Switching was fast as expected.

Hence i do not want to really use datagrid. I came across an alternative which says to use List\DataGroup with itemrenderer. But not sure how we can display around 10 columns. We can use a list with a label item renderer and we can adjust the space between each column value, something like this:
data.firstColValue   data.secondColValue  .....
But with this, I will not get the datagrid's column width increasing\decreasing functionality, which is very much needed in this project.

Is there a way in which we can remove heavy functionality and retain only core functionality(which is needed here) from datagrid? If not, are there any other alternatives with which I can achieve desired result?

Comment: Also - not sure how you are using the datagrid, if you are using item renderers make them light, make sure you turn on horizontal scrolling, etc. Search our blog for performance - there are a number of tips for optimizing the flex datagrids in general.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Flex has accepted donation of Mobile Datagrid component, so you may expect to see the component baked into future release of Flex Framework.

Comment: It's been merged into the release branch and will be available in the next version of Flex (4.11).